# Is it okay to ask a series of questions that follow a template?

Tags: discussion

In thinking about [the human vision system](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8043/), I'm reminded of the section in Michael Freeman's book on color in digital photography where he devotes a page to exploring each individual hue/color. I think something like that would be interesting/helpful here, and I'd like to do it as one question per hue/color. The questions would all be very similar, following a longer / better-thought-through / more-carefully written of a template like the following:

> How does [color] work in photography?
>   How is this color/hue perceived? What
>   feelings does the color typically
>   evoke? What cultural meanings do
>   people associate with this color, and
>   in what cultures? How does [color]
>   work in relation to specific other
>   colors? What unique strengths does
>   this color have when it dominates an
>   image? What if there's only small bits
>   of it? [And etc.]

I could ask this as a single question about *all* colors together, but that 1) demands long answers and 2) makes it hard for answers which have a great point about one particular color but not so much on others to rise and 3) seems like it'd get all muddled.

So, if I ask roughly a dozen questions following this pattern, would that be okay? Or does it seem spammy?

Comment: You could post questions once a month. Then we would have a weekly featured image + a monthly featured colour. :)

Comment: I'm not sure I have the attention span for once a month. :) But spacing them out is a good idea — thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your topic of choice seem to be pretty esoteric... But I will say that it TOTALLY may just be my take on it and there may be a real interest from the community for a bunch of these sorts of articles. I did my first lighting article and only then- based on the unexpected level of positive reaction I got- did I tackle the next one, and then based on additional "hey, I'm not being annoying with these lighting questions, am I?" feedback in chat I completed the lighting series. Maybe that's the way to more forward? Do one, see if there's a 'market' for your topic, and if there are a good number of people who are finding it useful, expand somewhat organically from there?

Personally I think it'd be a little annoying to have 12 new questions on the topic drop all at one time. :-) Not to mention that you probably wouldn't get the level of discussion that you'd like to gain enough good answers... But 12 questions over the course of... say... a month? That might work.

Just my thoughts, though. Don't take it as 'tha law.' ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I for one really appreciated Jay Lance's questions & answers on the various lighting setups; they got a lot of upvotes too. They were certainly formulaic, so having formulaic questions isn't itself bad.

Having a dozen questions on individual hues *seems* a bit over-detailed though. Would one hue deserve an upvote more than another? Would they garner different answers (besides yours)?

I'm saying this without knowing what the differences between hues are or what your answer would look like. Perhaps you could post one hue here in Meta so that we could judge?

Comment: I wish the relevant portion of the book I referenced were available online. Some of the book is at http://books.google.com/books?id=3ilf-lPA2kYC&lpg=PP1&ots=o4qNdcBNT4&dq=mastering%20color%20digital%20photography&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false , but not that chapter. It's really helpful stuff, but it is 1) just one person's answers, expert though he may be and 2) it's out of print, so not available to everyone. I'll see about constructing a more detailed example of what I'm thinking of.